# htaccess rewrite rule (remove old folder from google listings)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

any help would be awesome.

I have old listings in Google like
mysite.co.nz/shop/somerandomsegment/anotherrandomsegment 
I need to redirect people to 
mysite.co.nz/somerandomsegment/anotherrandomsegment 
I need it to string replace '/shop/' with '/'

How do I do this in htaccess?
cheers heaps

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the part `/shop` from the URL, use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/shop/(.*)|/shop)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2 [L,R=302]
```

It will do the following redirects:
From
`mysite.co.nz/shop`
to
`mysite.co.nz/shop`

From
`mysite.co.nz/shop/asd/test`
to
`mysite.co.nz/asd/test`, etc.